# What is a word for comparing two things but suggesting one is better than the other?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, synonyms

What is a word for comparing two things but suggesting one is better than the other?

For example: `John verbally compares a and b but hints that a is superior.`

*With what word would I replace compares so I can get rid of the second clause?*

Comment: John compares b against his preferred choice of a.   John goes through the motions of comparing b to his favored a.  John quickly discards b after a cursory comparison to a.

Comment: @Jim Sorry - My example was a bit unclear. I have revised it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider *[extol](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/extol)* (or *extoll*)

> to praise highly; laud

While *extol* does not require a comparison, it suggests an extensive praising that usually includes a detailed exposition of the value of the praised object.

> He extolled a over b.

The suggestion is that he waxed eloquent as to why a is better than b. A comparison may be implied.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of a word that means exactly what you're looking for.  *Contrasting* focuses on the differences between options A and B, and is often used when one is preferable to the other and you're trying to highlight why.  But it's not always so - you can contrast 'night' and 'day' without implying one is better than the other.

Answer (score 1):

"John favo(u)rably compares A {with / to} B".

Comment: Plus one. I was going to suggest "Compares B unfavourably with A" but that is, of course, the same thing in reverse. Not quite the word that the OP is looking for but I will be surprised if anyone comes up with a better answer.